# Success and Error callbacks both executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

When I examine my validUrlList and invalidUrlList, they are identical. Why are both callbacks fired?

```
filterPhotos: function(urlList) {
    var filterSuccess;
    var filterError;
    var i;

    filterSuccess = function (url) {
        pg_scope.validUrlList.push(url)
    };

    filterError = function (url) {
        pg_scope.invalidUrlList.push(url)
    };

    for (i=0; i<urlList.length; i++) {

        console.log(i);
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(urlList[i], filterSuccess(urlList[i]) , filterError(urlList[i]));


    }

},
```

Comment: because you're calling them rather than letting `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` call them. Call a function with `functionname()`, pass it with `functionname`

Comment: how can I pass the function name, including its parameter?

Comment: You have to instead pass it another function that then calls the original the way you want. You could also instead use .bind

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: uhm.... no i do not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the functions instead of correctly passing their handlers.

You should be doing this instead:
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(urlList[i], filterSuccess, filterError);

EDIT:
If you want to pass in parameters for those functions, one easy approach is to use closure:

```
var x = 2; // example parameter

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(urlList[i], 

function filterSuccess(url){
    pg_scope.validUrlList.push(url);
    console.log(x); // we can use x!
}, 

filterError);
```

Comment: How would I pass the url parameter to the success and error callbacks?

Comment: The first argument IS the URL parameter

Comment: I'm referring to the parameter that I need to pass to the success and error callbacks

Comment: @egekhter did you even try the code in this answer?

Comment: Yeah long time ago - it does me no good unless I have the data from the parameter in my success or or error code blocks.

Comment: If you want to pass an additional parameter to the callback, that's a question that has been asked many times. Google "javascript pass argument to callback"

Comment: @egekhter This answer answers your question. It may not solve the follow-up problem that you have, but it does directly answer the question you asked. It stops the success and error callbacks from both being called. If you have another problem you want to solve, you should research it separately and/or ask a separate question.

Comment: @egekhter I provided an example in my edit. There are other ways that Kevin B mentioned.